# Insert data into Redshift from Windows txt files

Tags: postgresql, copy, amazon-redshift

I have 50 `txt` files on windows and I would like to insert their data into a single table on `Redshift`.
I created the basic table structure and now I'm having issues with inserting the data. I tried using `COPY` command from `SQLWorkbench/J` but it didn't work out.

Here's the command:

```
copy feed
from 'F:\Data\feed\feed1.txt'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access>;aws_secret_access_key=<key>'
```

Here's the error:

```
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  CREDENTIALS argument is not supported when loading from file system
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     0
  location:  xen_load_unload.cpp:333
  process:   padbmaster [pid=1970]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

Upon removing the `Credentials` argument, here's the error I get:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: LOAD source is not supported. (Hint: only S3 or DynamoDB or EMR based load is allowed);
```

I'm not a `UNIX` user so I don't really know how this should be done. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a safe bet Amazon's servers can't read your `F:\` drive. It looks like Redshift can [read data from an S3 bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_data.html) so you could try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@patthebug is correct in that Redshift cannot see your local Windows drive.  You must push the data into an S3 bucket.  There are some additional sources you can use per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading_tables_with_the_COPY_command.html, but they seem outside the context you're working with.  I suggest you get a copy of Cloudberry Explorer (http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) which you can use to copy those files up to S3.